# What is play instance

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, playframework

I am to deploy a scala project on AWS. Many a sites are talking about "Play instances". So, I am little confused. What it is exactly and how it is helpful in successful deployment.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I would say that Play instance is a running Play application. AWS instances are explained here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Answer (score 1):

Play is a framework which makes it easy to develop web applications in Java or Scala. It is unrelated to AWS. Play allows you to develop test and debug locally. When you want to deploy your Play application to AWS, a very straightforward way (though not the only way) is to use the `play war` command to generate a WAR file of your application, then use Elastic Beanstalk to deploy it to AWS EC2 instances running Tomcat.

More information about Elastic Beanstalk is here: http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/

I am guessing what people are calling a "Play instance" is a Play application running on an EC2 instance.